# How to retrieve shared notebooks using the MS Graph API (beta endpoint)

Tags: onenote, microsoft-graph-api

According to [OneNote in the Microsoft Graph API (in Preview)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2015/11/18/onenote-in-the-microsoft-graph-api-in-preview/) it should be possible to retrieve and access notebooks owned by the user and shared by other users (plus O365 group notebooks).

However, executing https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/notes/notebooks just returns my (owned) notebooks (not the shared ones). So maybe I'm doing something wrong here, but how do I list all notebooks that my user has access to (owned as well as shared) using the Graph API?

Comment: This endpoint shows me the onenote documents which were shared with me through onedrive. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/sharedWithMe perhaps there are other endpoints which show the documents shared by sharepoint. I couldn't find a unified way to access all onenote documents that are currently shared with me. See more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-get-content

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the confusion, OliverL. We've updated the blog post to clarify that the */me* endpoint currently only provides access to the OneNote content that’s owned by the current user.

Soon the */me* endpoint will also include OneNote content that others have shared with the current user, and then you'll be able to get a list of shared notebooks. But right now, you can only use the */users/<id>* or */users/<userPrincipalName>* endpoint to access content that another user (specified in the URL) has shared with the current user.

We'll announce the upcoming change in the [OneNote Dev Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev) when we release it, and make note of it here too. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Hi. How we can get the id/userPrincipleName details of the user who has shared the notebook. Please reply. This is kind of blocker for me